US visa from the Philippines
I am a US citizen.  I married a Filipina lady (resident of the Philippines) over a year ago and would like her to travel to the US for a visit, but every attempt at getting a travel visa has been turned down by the embassy, WITHOUT any reason given.  This has happened once so far.  She does not currently have a job.  This was not done via an agency, but through a person by the name of Jim Mace.  She paid the fee directly at the embassy.
Is there any kind of way to get through this problem, that any of you might know of?

More information, please! Are you a US citizen? It not, what citizenship do you have? Do you live in the US? Is she resident in the Philippines? What refusal reason are you getting? 214(b)? How many refusals does she have? Does she have a job?

Did you apply directly with the embassy or through some kind of agency?

Related question How to prove ties to home country

"without any reason given" seems unusual, unless the application was made through an agency. Some agencies are fraudulent, and take the applicant's money without even making an application. Ask the agency for a copy of the refusal letter.

...ask the agency for the actual refusal letter.

Do you live in the Philippines with her, or in the US, or somewhere else?

What exact visa type did she apply for (specific letter and number, like B-1)?  I am not sure about this, but there might be an issue with applying for a visitor visa like B-1/B-2, because they require convincing the government that she will leave after the temporary visit, and as spouse of a US citizen she has an obvious reason to want to stay.  There is a separate process for spousal visas leading to permanent residency, and perhaps you want to be on that track instead.

But this guy Jim Mace seems to be unhelpful at best (fraudulent at worst).  Consider working with a reputable immigration attorney instead.

IDK who ‘Jim Mace’ is or why you did the application through him rather than just doing it yourselves. Assuming that the application itself was correctly completed and all relevant / available supporting documents were provided, you could:

ask your wife about the interview to identify any aspects that could have contributed to the refusal and how to address them
ask to see the actual refusal letter and address the reason(s) given
get advice from a reputable immigration lawyer.

You mention that your wife does not currently have a job. The  most likely reason is that your wife’s circumstances in her home country
were not sufficiently strong to overcome the US presumption of
immigrant intent INA Section 214(b) - Visa Qualifications and
Immigrant
Intent. If your wife was found ineligible under section 214(b) of the INA, she will need to be able to present evidence of significant changes in circumstances since the refused application to make reapplying as a visitor worthwhile.
As an aside, the ‘B’ visa refusal rate for Filipino applicants was nearly 24% in 2023.
